# Should I end with "Yours sincerely" or "Yours faithfully" when writing to editor?

Tags: word-choice, letter-writing

I've read from other questions here that we should use "Yours sincerely" when we know the name of the recipient and "Yours faithfully" if we're writing to "Sir/Madam". Then what about "Dear Editor" and "Dear Parents" or "Dear Teachers"? Which one should I end with?

Can anybody help me out here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know the name of the editor? If you do, then address  him or her with their name and end the letter/email with *sincerely*. If the communication is *very* formal and  the names of all or some of the recipients are known (teachers, parents etc.) then end the message in the same way.

Comment: I always learned that you were sincere to your friends and had to have faith in others.

Comment: Yes, the “rule” described by Mari-Lou A remains correct for very formal written correspondence. It is however weakening with time and with the gradual demise of paper “snail mail”. The previous post (link provided by Mari-Lou) was started 9 years ago and yet, even then, Osh provided a possible (non-preferred) answer listing the many possible modern alternatives to the firmly enforced  conventions of yesteryear. For example, I can easily imagine a letter to an editor closing with “Thank you, ...”.

Comment: I doubt that anyone important to whom you wish to write these days either knows or cares which is "correct", or would even notice which form you use.  Old books of etiquette can show you what to do if you really want to be pedantic about it, but I doubt that anyone would be impressed. I write this comment as someone who more than once was required to sign off as " I remain,Sir, your obedient servant". That has all gone now.